# Snakes and Ladders: Displaying grid in dialog box

Tags: java

I am coding a Snakes and Ladders game and I have most of the logic sorted out, except for the method displaying the grid in a message dialog.

```
private static void generateGrid() {

    String[][] board = new String[][] {
        { "48", "47", "46", "45", "44", "43", "42" },
        { "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41" },
        { "34", "33", "32", "31", "30", "29", "28" },
        { "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27" },
        { "20", "19", "18", "17", "16", "15", "14" },
        { "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13" },
        { "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "0" } };

    String grid = "";

    for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) { // This counts the number of
                                                // rows

        for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++) { // This counts the number
                                                    // of columns

            if ((board[x][y] + "").length() == 1) {

                grid = grid + board[x][y] + "   \t";

            } else {

                grid = grid + board[x][y] + "   \t";

            }

            grid = grid + "\n";
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, grid);      

    }
}
```

I want the grid displayed in the message dialog to have the same layout as in the array, but when I run my program, this is the end result:

[image: this is the end result]

How do I get it so that when the grid is displayed, the order of the numbers follows the layout shown in the array?

Comment: The "\t" in the the else statement should be "\n"?

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the statement `grid = grid + "\n";` after every number and thus add a new line after every element of the array. The correct code looks as follows:

```
private static void generateGrid() {

    String[][] board = new String[][] {
        { "48", "47", "46", "45", "44", "43", "42" },
        { "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41" },
        { "34", "33", "32", "31", "30", "29", "28" },
        { "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27" },
        { "20", "19", "18", "17", "16", "15", "14" },
        { "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13" },
        { "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "0" } };

    String grid = "";

    for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) { // This counts the number of
                                            // rows
        for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++) { // This counts the number
                                                // of columns
            if ((board[x][y] + "").length() == 1) {
                grid = grid + board[x][y] + "   \t";
            } else {
                grid = grid + board[x][y] + "   \t";
            }

        }

        grid = grid + "\n";
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, grid);      
}
```

To find the solution to similar problems yourself, next time either use an IDE  with a debugger (like Eclipse or NetBeans) and step through the code, or simply add System.out.println() commands, such that you can see the values of your variables at every step.